# wp sql query for gettining posts category and media path

Tags: php, sql, json, wordpress

I want to create json code of posts in wordpress.
so I need post title, post categories and post media (if exist)
I think first I should write a sql query.
I wrote some thing like this for media but it doesn't help:

```
    SELECT t1.id, 
       t1.post_content, 
       t1.post_title, 
       t1.post_status, 
       t1.post_name, 
       t1.post_type 
FROM   `wp_posts` AS t1 
       JOIN `wp_posts` AS t2 
         ON t2.post_parent = t1.id 
WHERE  t1.post_type = 'post'
```

and I use this for getting category fo posts:

```
SELECT p.post_title, t.name FROM wp_posts as p

join `wp_term_relationships` as tr on p.ID = tr.object_id

join wp_terms as t on tr.term_taxonomy_id=t.term_id

where p.post_type='post'
```

Can any one help?